# White scrollbar on ROXTerm

Tags: 15.10, gtk3, 16.04

My ROXTerm GTK3 has rather irritating white scrollbars. Does anyone know how can I remove that white background?

Screenshot of my ROXTerm:

[ROXTerm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUQZd.png)

Screenshot of Gnome Terminal:

[Gnome Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BNvd.png)